# What type of projects can I host on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I hosted an Angular 4 project in Firebase hosting.
What firebase documentation page say is ***deploy your web app or static assets***.
All I want to know is what other type of projects or technologies I can host on Firebase Hosting.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Doug knows his stuff Hilal. He's a [Google Developer Advocate with the Firebase team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson). Bask in his wisdom

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy anything you want that requires static content to be delivered over HTTPS.